# How can I use 2d array in Django's template in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, python, django

I have a 2d array named "pre" in views.py . I have passed the same array in the template.html . I want to use the values of second column of each row of pre array as initial value for text boxes. Script is shown below.

Variable i.toString() is working fine with name of input tag but in values it is not working. 
I want the value of {{pre.0.2}} as values of 1st textbox,{{ pre.1.2}} as value of second one and so on. How can I achieve that ?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var max_fields = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
        var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
        var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

        var x = {{branches}}; //initlal text box count

        for (var i = 1; i <= x; i++) {

            if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed

                $(wrapper).append('<input name="main_address_'+i.toString()+'" value="{{pre.'+i.toString()+'.2}}" type="text" required=""><br>'); //add input box   
            }

        }
</script>
```

If you have any other way to achieve the same result please share it with me.

Comment: Why not use another data structure to extract those values from the 2d array in your views.py before passing it to the template? In this case, you might not even need any javascript code.

Comment: I'm not sure what the point of the JS is here. You're not don't anything dynamic; why not output the fields directly in the template code?

Comment: Plus, you seem to have completely misunderstood when template code is evaluated. There is **no possible way** for JS code to dynamically evaluate a template variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's very true that I don't need to use jQuery here. It can be easily implemented by {% for loop %} {% endfor %} in Django. Thanks for your comments.

```
{% for p in pre %}<input name="main_address_{{forloop.counter}}" value="{{p.2}}" type="text" required="">{% endfor %}
```